# Define a function $f$ such that the sum is a riemann-sum

Tags: calculus

I'm currently working on a problem which sounds as follows

Define a function $f$, such that 
$$\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^ni\exp \left(-\frac{2i^2}{n^2}\right )$$.
is a riemannsum on [0,1] and compute $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^ni\exp(-\frac{2i^2}{n^2})$$

I was originally thinking that setting $x_i=\frac{i}{n}$, we get $\Delta x_i=x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{i+1-i}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$

Since the definite integral $$\int_a^bf(t)dt=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x_i$$

I was thinking I could pull the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ term into the sum to get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{n}\exp \left(\frac{-2i^2}{n^2}\right)\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1te^{-2t^2}dt=\frac{e^2-1}{4e^2}$$

My question is

1. Did I do it right?
2. I don't know how I explicitly determine the "function" so to speak. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: wrote my integral wrong.

Comment: You are correct in your derivation. The function is simply $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t) = t e^{-2t^2}$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The first sum you wrote doesn't mention $f$ at all.  Is $f$ equal to that sum?  The sum is free in $x$ too...

Comment: Just fix your equation above, there is a limit missing.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Mistake on my part, will edit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, and it can be consensed in a single line:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\tfrac{k}{n}\right) e^{-2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}=\int_{0}^{1} x e^{-2x^2}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto\sqrt{z}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-2z}\,dz=\color{red}{\frac{1-e^{-2}}{4}}. $$